# MATLAB: Newton's method to Halley's method

Tags: matlab

I have this MATLAB code for Newton's method, and I'm trying to write a modified version for it to create Halley's method. The code is

```
function root = newton(fname,fdname, fd2name, x,xtol,ftol,n_max,display)
% Newton's Method.
%
% input:  fname is a string that names the function f(x).
%         fdname is a tring that names the derivative f'(x).
%         x is the initial point
%         xtol and ftol are termination tolerances
%         n_max is the maximum number of iteration
%         display = 1 if step-by-step display is desired,
%                 = 0 otherwise
% output: root is the computed root of f(x)=0
%
n = 0;
fx = feval(fname,x);
if display, 
   disp('   n             x                    f(x)')
   disp('------------------------------------------------------')
   disp(sprintf('%4d %23.15e %23.15e', n, x, fx))
end
if abs(fx) <= ftol
   root = x;
   return
end
for n = 1:n_max
    fdx = feval(fdname,x);
    d = fx/fdx;
    x = x - d;
    fx = feval(fname,x);
    if display, 
       disp(sprintf('%4d %23.15e %23.15e', n, x, fx)), end
    if abs(d) <= xtol | abs(fx) <= ftol
       root = x;
       return
    end
end
root = x;
```

I know that I have to change mostly the code in the for loop.

So I've changed:

```
fd2x = feval(fd2name, x)

d = 2*fx*fdx/(2*fdx.^2 - fxfd2x)
```

Does that make sense? What else do I have to change?

Comment: I assume you mean `d = 2*fx*fdx/(2*fdx.^2 - fx*fd2x)` (note the asterisk) . Also, do you have a problem with this code? does it run? have you tried it?

Comment: @AnderBiguri it gives me this error Undefined function 'fd2' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: Because your variable is called `fd2x` not `fd2`. Still , the code you show doesnt have anywhere `fd2` thus you are not showing the code that gives that error.